# Can't deploy or manage to Azure cloud service (classic) e.g. web role, is there a way to reboot?

Tags: azure, deployment, timeout, webrole

I've been deploying to my cloud service/web role pretty regularly for over a year with no issues.  But suddenly, today, my deployment bombed with the following error:

> The HTTP request to
>   'https://management.core.windows.net/*****/services/hostedservices/*****?embed-detail=true'
>   has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to
>   this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

And when I attempt to view the resource in the Azure portal dashboard, it eventually times out and displays a rain cloud icon. I get the same timeout and rain cloud icon when clicking on "Roles and Instances".

Azure's status page shows my region "West US" doesn't have any issues.

Interestingly, I can still access my application via the browser, so some instance is there and running, I just can't deploy updates to it or manage it in any way via the Azure portal.

What are my options here?  I was hoping I could RDP into it and force it to reboot or restart IIS or something, but everything I click on related to the cloud service in the portal times out.  I'd hate to have to attempt to delete it and create a new one as it's a pain to get the settings in sync, and often times I can't name it the same, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably this is just a network issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802142/http-request-timeout-windows-azure-deploy

Answer (score 0):

So, after going down the rabbit hole for about an hour playing around with the new Cloud Shell feature from the Azure portal to see if I could reboot it via a power shell command, the issue seems to have resolved itself.  I guess it was some sort of temporary hiccup with Azure or something, but I can now see my cloud service/web role in the portal and can now deploy to it.

Comment: There was an Azure-wide issue with classic Azure management actions recently